# Irregular login failure during Android and WCF communication

Tags: c#, android, wcf, login-control

I am creating a simple login module. During the completion and testing, I noticed that there was a problem with the WCF server and Android communication. The problem is that the login fails randomly. I searched on stack overflow msdn and so on, but I find it difficult to find the answer. Please help me.

Service1.svc.cs

```
public bool LogIn(string id, string pw)
{
    GEODB db = new GEODB();
    return db.LogIn(id, pw);
}
```

IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "LogIn", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
bool LogIn(string id, string pw);
```

GEODB.cs

```
public bool LogIn(string id, string pw)
{
    string strSQL = string.Empty;

    if (id[0].Equals('S'))
    {
        strSQL = "select * from Student where scode = replace('" + id + "', ' ', '') and spw = '" + pw +  "'";
        idFlag = "S";
    }
    else if (id[0].Equals('P'))
    {
        strSQL = "select * from parents where pid = replace('" + id + "', ' ', '') and pwd = '" + pw + "'";
        idFlag = "P";
    }
    else if (id[0].Equals('T'))
    {
        strSQL = "select * from teacher where tid = replace('" + id + "', ' ', '') and tpw = '" + pw + "'";
        idFlag = "T";
    }
    else if (id[0].Equals(null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);

    return LogIn_ReadQuery(cmd);
}


private bool LogIn_ReadQuery(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    try
    {
        string id = null;

        SqlDataReader myDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (myDataReader.Read())
        {
            if (idFlag == "S")
                id = myDataReader["sid"].ToString();
            else if (idFlag == "P")
                id = myDataReader["pid"].ToString();
            else if (idFlag == "T")
                id = myDataReader["tid"].ToString();
            else if (idFlag == "N") { return false; }

        }
        idFlag = string.Empty;
        myDataReader.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();

        if (id != null) { return true; } else { return false; }
    }
    catch (Exception) {return false;}
}
```

Android logcat

```
05-08 12:12:15.409 950-1425/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 364

05-08 12:12:12.469 384-384/? E/SMD: DCD ON

05-08 12:12:19.879 950-2374/? E/SAMP_SPCMtest: setPackageLockingTimeBySPCM() :72

05-08 12:12:20.949 950-1137/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0

05-08 12:12:20.999 25356-25356/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()

05-08 12:12:21.009 25356-25356/? E/Zygote: v2

05-08 12:12:21.019 25356-25356/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable 
seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL

I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

I think the last line of code is probably the problem. However, no matter how I search ... I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: I thought you had to open the connection before executing the command so it should never work and you're swallowing the exception so you'd never know. Also plain text passwords and concatenated queries are a very bad idea.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i solved this problem